# Overriding variable in called feature

Tags: karate

I'm using Karate to write integration tests for a REST API. In all test scenarios I have to login users to get an authentification token for all calls related to the REST API. So I want to put the login logic into a separate Karate feature, so I don't have to copy and paste the login API call to all other Scenarios.

From the doku I was able to figure out how to call my login.feature in another feature (logout, with needs a logged in user). I'm also able to pass the username and password to the called login.feature from my calling logout.feature. But I also want my login.feature to be executable on it's own, so I have to define username and password in the login.feature. But if I do so, I'm not able to override this variables from the calling feature.

If I run the logout.feature like follows, the login.feature is not using the email parameter I'm providing in the logout.feature If I delete the email variable from login.feature, it is using the parameter from logout.feature, but then I can't run the login.feature on its own.

Calling logout.feature:

```
Feature: Login/Logout Test

  Background:
    * url urlBase http://localhost:5000
    * def login = call read('classpath:ires/session/login.feature') {email: "user1@test.com", password: "test"}
    * def authToken = login.authToken

  Scenario: Testing logout via PUT

    Given path '/sessions/logout'
    Given param TOKEN = authToken
    And request {}
    When method PUT
    Then status 202
```

Called login.feature:

```
Feature: Logs in the given user

  Background:
    * url urlBase http://localhost:5000
    * def email = "user2@test.com"
    * def password = "test"

  Scenario: Test login via POST

    Given path '/sessions/login'
    And request {email: '#(email)', password: '#(password)'}
    And print email
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And def authToken = response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is you can create a `login-caller.feature` that will call the `login.feature` with the proper argument passed. Another option is to have `email` and `password` defined globally in `karate-config.js`.

I don't recommend depending on undefined variables as it leads to maintainability problems in the long run, but you can do this kind of conditional check:

```
* def email = typeof email == 'undefined' ? 'user2@test.com' : email
```

Comment: Thanks! I kind of like the conditional check variant for now ;) but I see how it might lead to maintainability problems in the future.